# Alternate options for REORG...LONGLOBDATA for space management

Tags: db2, db2-luw

What are the alternate options and their pros/cons?

Answer (score 2):

An obvious alternative would be partitioning the table by time, eliminating the need for reorganization.

Comment: Merci. "partitioning the table by time" is something we can think of but is there any option to deal with this right now? @mustaccio

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE` routine like shown in the Example 1 at the [Moving tables online by using the ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE procedure](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=odmo-moving-tables-online-by-using-admin-move-table-procedure) link.